# Destructure object into an array

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have this object

```
const foo = {
    a: 'kitten',
    b: 'puppy',
    c: 'lion'
};
```

Destructuring it into variables goes like this

```
const { a, b, c } = foo;
```

Is there a one-liner how to desctructre this into an array, so that the result ist

```
const array = [a, b, c];
```

Comment: Are the keys always guaranteed to be ascending in lexical order?

Comment: What about `const array = Object.values(foo)` or `const array = ["a", "b", "c"].map((key) => foo[key])`? I’m not aware of a one-liner using destructuring.

Comment: @byxor nope. They are not.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I was not aware of the `Object.values()` function. Thats just as good!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no "one-liner" I know of that uses destructuring.

You can use one of these instead (which *don't* use destructuring):

(1)

```
const array = [foo.a, foo.b, foo.c]
```

(2, as pointed out by @Sebastian Simon)

```
const array = Object.values(foo);
```

(3, as pointed out by @Sebastian Simon)

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(k => foo[k]);
```

Comment: Option 1 and 3 guarantee the provided order.

Comment: Correct. The only downside is: You need to know the keys in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a function, destructure the wanted properties and return an array with the wanted order.

```js
const
    getABC = ({ a, b, c }) => [a, b, c],
    foo = { a: 'kitten', b: 'puppy', c: 'lion' };

console.log(getABC(foo));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   Object.entries(obj).forEach( ([key, value]) => { 
   console.log(`${key}: ${value}`)
```

- Here, Object.entries () give array of key: value pair. You can use results as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a de-structure into array from an object.

But if you want all the keys / values of the object in an array format, you can use these:

```
let obj = {
    a: 'kitten',
    b: 'puppy',
    c: 'lion'
};

let keyArray = Object.keys(obj); 
// keyArray = ['a','b','c']
let valuesArray = Object.values(obj);
// valuesArray = ['kitten', 'puppy', 'lion'];
```

Do note that the order of the array is not guaranteed to follow the order of the object.